# how to limit drag and drop to parent object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have rawimage inside a game object and want to move it by drag and drop but must not exceed parent gameobject

I can move the raw image but It can go anywhere in the canvas 
for that I calculate the border points and allow it if it stays in border but mouses eventdata.position gives world position.
how can I transform mouse position to position in game object?

Comment: This is a simple Google. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700059/unity-mouse-position-to-world-position-but-just-the-y-pos

Comment: @jiveturkey the question in your link is mouse position to WORLD position I am looking for local position 
If I was working on world positions I can simply write```transform.position=eventData.position``` but I want to set it from local position where parent gameobject is middle is 0,0

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the mouse position to world position then world position to local position

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
Vector3 objectRelative = object.transfrom.InverseTransformPoint(mousePos);
```

Comment: @eomer Yes ahah

Comment: I get an error:
'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'InverseTransformPoint' and no accessible extension method 'InverseTransformPoint' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: my bad, you need to do `gameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint()`, answer edited to reflect that

Comment: I dont get any error but makes no sense
I have a gameobject iwth height:570 and width:760 and anchors to middle
my raw image is width:100 height:100 
I write your code to pointerDown event to check
If I click on the raw image it must give a coordinate between -380 to 380 for x and -285 to285 for y but I for objectRelative I get (-403.7, -1005.5, -16.7)

Comment: the mouse position will be on the camera's clipping plane, you may have to alter it's Y position, or you can use `ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);` and use the position of the intersection of the ray with your object

Comment: it seems a little complicated
instead of transforming mouse position 
cant I just say dont go beyon your parent or something?

Comment: @eomer yes, perhaps i misunderstood your question. let me try a different approach, I'll write another answer

Comment: thx a lot maybe I asked wrong. new to unity and dont know how to name every problem correctly
If I dont let raw image drag beyond parent it will be enough for me
I also need coordinates but I can take raw images local postion after

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use collider bounds, these aren't always super accurate however, depending on the shape of your object
In your child object's update method, make sure you have [ExecuteInEditMode] at the top of your script

```
if(!Application.isPlaying){
    Vector3 minBounds, maxBounds;
    Collider parentCollider = transform.parent.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>();
    minBounds = parentCollider.bounds.min; 
    maxBounds = parentCollider.bounds.max;

    float xPos = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minBounds.x, maxBounds.x);
    float yPos = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minBounds.y, maxBounds.y);
    float zPos = Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.z, minBounds.z, maxBounds.z);

    transform.position = new Vector3(xPos,yPos,zPos);

}
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have some sort of collider attached to your parent object

Comment: also didnt understand the need for [ExecuteInEditMode] 
I was gonna copy your to OnDrag method since it is running when draggingg

Comment: I couldnt manage to work the collider. I read about it and collider not working good when you are working with ui.

so I've come up with a different solution I put an empty object same sizes with raw image and ondrag set position of that gameobject first and if that empty objects local position are in bounds of parent change raw Images position.

dumb but simple :D